# Body mass index calculator in Swift

Tags: beginner, mvc, swift, calculator

Today I created my second app - a simple body mass index calculator. The BMI is calculated by the following formula:

$$\dfrac{\text{weight}}{\text{(height)}^2}$$

The general meaning of the resulting BMI values:

- \$<18.5\$ = underweight
- \$18.5-25\$ = normal weight
- \$25-30\$ = overweight
- \$>30\$ = obese

My goal was to improve my skills and make something useful at the same time. I'm sharing my code in hope to get some constructive feedback. Is there anything I could improve?

My model file:

```
import Foundation

struct CalculatorBrain {
let weightInKG: Double
let heightInCM: Double

init(weightInKG: String, heightInCM: String) {
    self.weightInKG = Double(weightInKG) ?? 0.0
    self.heightInCM = Double(heightInCM) ?? 0.0
}

func calcBmi() -> Double {
    return weightInKG / ((heightInCM / 100) * (heightInCM / 100))
}
}
```

The ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var weightTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var heightTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var resultTextField: UILabel!

@IBAction func calculateBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let weightInKG = weightTextField.text,
        let heightInCM = heightTextField.text else {
            return
    }
    let cm = CalculatorBrain(weightInKG: weightInKG, heightInCM: heightInCM)
    let result = cm.calcBmi()
    resultTextField.text = "BMI: \(result)"
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me just congratulate you on some really good naming! It's a great idea to put the units in the variable name. I just spent the better part of a day on a tight deadline chasing down a bug that ended up being a units issue. I felt so stupid. The only named I'd work on improving is `result`. Why not just call it `bmi`? `result` is a very generic name unless you're writing something like a square root function. It doesn't tell you what it's the result of.

It seems a little weird to me that `init` takes its parameters as `String`s and immediately converts them to `Double`. Why not have the model object just take them as `Double` and let the controller convert them? If you ever reuse this class or expand it for a task where the data doesn't come from a text field (like maybe it comes from a database or the health app), you may not have the values as `String`s. It seems most efficient to have the `init` method take them in the format they'll be stored in and let the caller worry about doing the conversion.

Indentation styles are a personal thing. My preference would be to indent everything between the open and close braces of a `struct` or `class`. It's a minor thing, but I feel it improves readability, especially if you end up needing to put more than one in the same header.

Comment: Hi @user1118321 !
Thank you very much for your feedback. This really helps me to improve, especially your idea on how I can improve my init with the type conversion.

Answer (score 3):

I have some minor tips about naming:

- `weight` is entirely different than `mass`, thus I advice you to change that, because some users might be annoyed by this common confusion, if it is present in the user interface of the app. See ***[Mass versus weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_versus_weight)***
- `CalculatorBrain` does not really feel related to `BMI`. Maybe `BMICalculator` would be a better fit here

---

When it comes to your `struct`, if that is all you are planning to do with it, this gets quite useless. Instead, I would simply use a function, taking two `Double` parameters (to avoid `String` conversion). Also, I would not use `((heightInCM / 100) * (heightInCM / 100))`, because it does an unnecessary multiplication between two known numbers, two of `100` in this case. This would be an example:

```
func calculateBMI(massInKilograms mass: Double, heightInCentimeters height: Double) -> Double {
    return mass / ((height * height) / 10000)
}
```

It is shorter and, in my opinion, more elegant and efficient. And now you do not need to initialize a `struct` and call one of its methods each time, instead you only need to call it:

```
calculateBMI(massInKilograms: x, heightInCentimeters: y)
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to Code Review! This looks like a fine first answer. I see you have already read through the [tour], so there's nothing left to do for me here.

Comment: Thank you @Graipher! Being used to the other Stack Exchange sites helps.

Comment: Hi @Mr.Xcoder, I really like your tips. I thought about changing `((heightInCM / 100) * (heightInCM / 100))` as well because like you already said it doesn't look elegant at all. Now I have a way to improve this part of my code which I'm really thankful for. Have a nice day!